# How to count elements in an array depending on value

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array of Answer Entities that has an structure that includes an array of Vthumbs.

Entities that can either have a boolean vthumbdown/vthumbup property.

And the problem is this: How can I count the number of elements in the Vthumbs array that have a true "vthumbdown" (and the number of elements that have false "vthumbup")?

```
  {
    "accepted": true,
    "creationDate": "2018-12-21T15:42:34.497Z",
    "id": 0,
    "urlvanser": "string",
    "userId": 0,
    "vquestionId": 0,
    "vthumbs": [
      {
        "creationDate": "2018-12-21T15:42:34.497Z",
        "id": 0,
        "userId": 0,
        "vanswerId": 0,
        "vquestionId": 0,
        "vthumbdown": true,
        "vthumbup": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can see the total number of items with {{vanswer.vthumbs.length}} but I can not think how to get the number of Ups and Downs

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this simply by filtering the array:

```
const ups = vanswer.vthumbs.filter(v => v.vthumbup).length;
const downs= vanswer.vthumbs.filter(v => v.vthumbdown).length;
```

Then use it in your template:

```
Ups: {{ ups }}
Downs: {{ downs }}
```

Edit: according to comments, you wanna count these things in the template. For that, you can build a simple pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'countThumbs'
})
export class CounterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any, upsOrDowns = 'ups'): any {
    if (!obj.vthumbs || !Array.isArray(obj.vthumbs)) {
      return null;
    }
    if (upsOrDowns === 'ups') {
      return obj.vthumbs.filter(item => item.vthumbup).length;
    } else {
      return obj.vthumbs.filter(item => item.vthumbdown).length
    }
  }
}
```

You then use it in the template like this:

```
Thumbups: {{ vanswer | countThumbs:'ups' }}
Thumbdowns: {{ vanswer | countThumbs:'downs' }}
```

Here's a more generic approach at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-counter-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: But I have an array of vanswers... can I get that result with an NgIf as the NgFor is being populated... or something else but within my HTML code? Thanks for your help

Comment: You can but it's simpler and better this way. You can do it with, e.g. a pipe that can count this for you, e.g. like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-counter-pipe?file=src/app/counter.pipe.ts

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try with the pipe... it looks good!     If i use the filter I would have to make a lot of changes to include the Ups and Downs together its corresponding part in the array, right?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like a lot of changes to me, but I may not understand your use case well. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: @JorgeM.Nures Updated my answer with the pipe specific to your `vanswer` object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great reference on javascript arrays and their available methods on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). In this instance you would most likely want to utilize the [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as follows.

```
vanswer.vthumbs.filter(vthumb => vthumb.vthumbdown).length;
vanswer.vthumbs.filter(vthumb => vthumb.vthumbup).length;
```

Comment: But I have an array of vanswers... can I get that result with an NgIf as the NgFor is being populated... or something else but within my HTML code? Thanks for your help